# Using a bit mask to partially swap part of a number with another

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let,

```
a    = xxxxxxxx
b    = yyyyyyyy
mask = 11100000
```

What bitwise methods can I use to end up with

```
d    = yyyxxxxx
```

Comment: Try solving it yourself. What operations might you use? What stumbling blocks do you run into that you need help with?

Comment: @amalloy I have. For quite some time. Hence why I'm posting... I see no need to add details that would complicate the question and/or steer possible solutions a certain direction

Comment: In more usual terminology, this might be called "merging bits according to a mask" (which yields relevant search results), though I can see why you called it this.

Comment: @JetBlue I can assure you, it never hurts to add as much detail as possible in solving the question. You're only helping us help you. It's very rare that people "show too much effort".

Comment: @harold Thanks for that search keyword. Definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)
```

`a & ~mask` gets you the `000xxxxx` part, and `b & mask` gets you the `yyy00000` part. You can then combine them with a bitwise OR.